# Make code wait a certain time but stop waiting in case there is another touch

Tags: java, android, ontouchlistener

My code is the following:

```
ss.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                int loucodecatuaba = 0;

               if (event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                   redBlock.setY(event.getY()-(imagewidth));
                   redBlock.setX(event.getX()-(imageheight));
                   return  true;
               }
               if (event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                        try {

                            Thread.sleep(1000);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        }


                   redBlock.setX(centroX);
                   redBlock.setY(centroY);
               }

               return false;
            }
        })
```

What I want is for the program to wait for the 1000 milliseconds unless there is another click, in which case it should go back to the first if loop ( the one with "event.getAction()==MotionEvente.ACTION_DOWN")

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to do that better, is more like a version of mister MeLine code.

```
final Thread dois = new Thread(){
public void run() {

        try{
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        redBlock.setX(centroX);
        redBlock.setY(centroY);
        }catch (InterruptedException e){
        }


        }
        };


        ss.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, final MotionEvent event) {





        if (event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){

        dois.interrupt();
        redBlock.setY(event.getY()-(imagewidth));
        redBlock.setX(event.getX()-(imageheight));

        return  true;
        }
        if (event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
        dois.start();

        }

        return false;
        }
        });
}
```

By creating the thread outside the onTouchListener I can set a timer and stop and restart it better.

Answer (score 0):

You should start a new thread and and should have a global boolean value isWaitingStarted.

```
            boolean isWaitingStarted = false;
                ...
                if (event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                      if(!isWaitingStarted){
                          isWaitingStarted = true;
                          Thread one = new Thread() {
                              public void run() {
                                  try {

                                       Thread.sleep(1000);

                                       setRedBlock();
                                   } catch(InterruptedException v) {          
                                   }
                             }  
                           };

                        one.start();
                      } 
                } else {
                    setRedBlock(); 
                }
```

Try to declare a method:

```
public void setRedBlock() {
   redBlock.setX(centroX);
   redBlock.setY(centroY);
   isWaitingStarted = false;
}
```

Comment: But in that case wouldn't the code wait exactly 1000 milliseconds? what I want is let say when the user stop touching (ACTION_UP) the code start waiting, but if passed 800 milliseconds of waiting the user touch the screen again, the waiting stop and the "if (event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)" code starts running again

Comment: if(!isWaitingStarted) will bypass the creating of new waiting thread

Comment: It prompts me this "error" ("Variable 'isWaitingStarted' is accessed from within inner class, needs to be declared final")

Comment: it keeps saying expression expected ';' expected in the "public void setRedBlock"

Comment: I missed ";" after the method call

Comment: glad could be of help